# Perform two operations in one button click: loading and checking checkbox in gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, checkbox

**Current Scenario**

First operation: Load the data in gridview using a sql query passed to Select comman in sqldatasource.(USING PROCESS BUTTON -  ExecuteQuery Function)

Second operation: Check the checkbox in gridview per row when the date in that row also existed in another table - discount table (USING RECOMPUTE BUTTON - CheckApproveDisc function)

**Here's the code:**

```
    protected void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            }
                executeQuery();

            }


 protected void btnRecompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckApproveDisc();

    }
```

and

```
   public void executeQuery()
            {

                 if ((ddlLoc.SelectedValue == "ALL LOCATIONS") && (ddlRP.SelectedValue == "PER RETAIL PARTNER"))
                {
                    if (txtSearchedRP.Text == "")
                    {
                        string script = "alert(\"Please select a Retail Partner\");";
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                              "ServerControlScript", script, true);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        dstrQuery = @"select a.tenantcode,   b.name , convert(varchar(10), a.date, 101) as Date, datename(weekday, a.date) as Day,
                                convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.surcharge ) as money),1) AS Surcharge, 
                                convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.senior)  as money),1) as senior, 
                                convert(varchar,cast((((SUM(a.senior))/0.20)*0.80)  as money),1) as VATExemptSales,
                                convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.other)  as money),1) as Other, 
                                convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.refund)  as money),1)as Refund, 
                                convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.void)  as money),1) as Void, 

                                case when a.date IN (select Z.date from discount z where z.date between '"+ txtdatefrom.Text  +"' and '"+ txtdateto.Text  +"' and z.tenantcode = '" + hdnRP.Value + "') THEN (convert(varchar,cast(((sum(a.cash) + SUM(a.charge) + SUM(a.gift)) - (SUM(a.surcharge))) as money),1) ) ELSE convert(varchar,cast(((sum(a.cash) + SUM(a.charge) + SUM(a.gift)+ SUM(a.other)) - (SUM(a.surcharge))) as money),1) end as GSC, convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.cash ) as money),1) as Cash, convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.charge ) as money),1) as Charge, convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.gift ) as money),1) as Gift from  TENANT b inner join LOCATION c on b.location=c.location inner join DAILY a on a.tenantcode=b.tenantcode   where (a.date between '" + txtdatefrom.Text + "' and '" + txtdateto.Text + "')  and (a.tenantcode = '" + hdnRP.Value + "') GROUP BY a.tenantcode, b.name, a.date order by  a.date ";



                        sqlDataSourceDSRTender.SelectCommand = dstrQuery;


                    }
                }

                CheckApproveDisc();
            }
```

--

```
 public void CheckApproveDisc()
    {
        int RecordCount = 0;
        string datepass;


        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdDSTR.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCheckRow") as CheckBox);

                try
                {
                    datepass = (row.Cells[2].Text);
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(datepass);

                    string queryString = "select COUNT(*) from DISCOUNT Where date = '" + dt + "' and tenantcode = '" + hdnRP.Value + "'";


                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
                    con.Open();
                    RecordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                    if (RecordCount == 1)
                    {
                        chkRow.Checked = true;
                    }

                    con.Close();
                }


                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Response.Write("Something wrong happened");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**What I want to achieve**

To execute both operation in ONE BUTTON CLICK ONLY. I tried including two functions in Process Button but it is not working, maybe it is because The system is not yet done loading the gridview data so the iteration process, testing each row is not working.

Are there other ways or alternative to achieve this?

--

**UPDATED**

I think this is partly the answer, but it's not 100% accurate, i include ON DATA BINDING PROPERTY IN the checkbox (PLEASE SEE CODE BELOW). The problem left here is the last row is not checking or not taking effect on the last row of the gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDSTR" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceDSRTender" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" 
                         ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" 
                        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" width="100%" Font-Size="Smaller" PageSize="31"  >

                        <emptydatarowstyle backcolor="white" forecolor="black"/> <emptydatatemplate> No Data Found.</emptydatatemplate> 

                         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

                        <Columns>


                    <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheckRow" runat="server" OnDataBinding="btnProcess_Click"  />
       </ItemTemplate>

                           <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="ckhCheckAll" runat="server" onclick="GridSelectAllColumn(this);" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>

                         </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Did you try to call CheckApproveDisc() in btnProcess_Click?

Comment: Yes.. i did but it is no good and I dont know why it is not working. Please see the code above. Thanks

Comment: What might be happening is you set the SelectCommand on the SqlDataSource, but it hasn't yet executed the command and fetched the rows yet. Instead of iterating over the rows like you are, handle one of the GridRow events to check its properties, and in there set the checkbox cell as needed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and that can be the reason, with your answer  please explain further. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean using a row command event for the gridview? sorry for this question, I am quite new to asp.net programming. Will that be able to achieve what I need to happen, performing both operation in  on button click event?

Answer (score 0):

"Perform two operations in one button click"? I suggest you give [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) a try. To see how you can use BackgroundWorker on web Application  see this  [question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1246781.aspx?Can+background+worker+be+used+for+web+based+application+)  .Or  important. add Async ="true" on the page you want to use backgroundworker like below. If you are using on desktop app u dont need this line of code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" ... Inherits="_Default" Async ="true" %>
```

///

```
protected void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker w = new BackgroundWorker();
    w.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(doWork)
    w.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(workComplete);
     if (w.IsBusy != true)
      {
          // Start the asynchronous operation.
           w.RunWorkerAsync();
       }

    }
    protected void doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       //Put your  executeQuery(); here 

      if ((ddlLoc.SelectedValue == "ALL LOCATIONS") && (ddlRP.SelectedValue == "PER RETAIL PARTNER"))
           {
                if (txtSearchedRP.Text == "")
                   {
                       string script = "alert(\"Please select a Retail Partner\");";
                       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,       
                                     GetType(),"ServerControlScript",script, true);
                    }
                  else
                    {
                       dstrQuery = @"select a.tenantcode,   b.name , convert(varchar(10), a.date, 101) as Date, datename(weekday, a.date) as Day,
                                    convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.surcharge ) as money),1) AS Surcharge, 
                                    convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.senior)  as money),1) as senior, 
                                    convert(varchar,cast((((SUM(a.senior))/0.20)*0.80)  as money),1) as VATExemptSales,
                                    convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.other)  as money),1) as Other, 
                                    convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.refund)  as money),1)as Refund, 
                                    convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.void)  as money),1) as Void, 

                                    case when a.date IN (select Z.date from discount z where z.date between '"+ txtdatefrom.Text  +"' and '"+ txtdateto.Text  +"' and z.tenantcode = '" + hdnRP.Value + "') THEN (convert(varchar,cast(((sum(a.cash) + SUM(a.charge) + SUM(a.gift)) - (SUM(a.surcharge))) as money),1) ) ELSE convert(varchar,cast(((sum(a.cash) + SUM(a.charge) + SUM(a.gift)+ SUM(a.other)) - (SUM(a.surcharge))) as money),1) end as GSC, convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.cash ) as money),1) as Cash, convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.charge ) as money),1) as Charge, convert(varchar,cast(SUM(a.gift ) as money),1) as Gift from  TENANT b inner join LOCATION c on b.location=c.location inner join DAILY a on a.tenantcode=b.tenantcode   where (a.date between '" + txtdatefrom.Text + "' and '" + txtdateto.Text + "')  and (a.tenantcode = '" + hdnRP.Value + "') GROUP BY a.tenantcode, b.name, a.date order by  a.date ";



                            sqlDataSourceDSRTender.SelectCommand = dstrQuery;


                        }
                    } 
      //Bind your gridview.
    }
    protected void workComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       //This event is called when the dowork complete
       CheckApproveDisc();

    }
```

. BAckgroundworker is a powerful class . It has progresschanged event . All your message and progress such as `string script = "alert(\"Please select a Retail Partner\");";` you can bring them here . Your grid also you can bind it base on progresschange or just in the do work. After everything is finished then you can do your checkbox checking event in workercomplete method. This is a powerful class do check the msdn page and the links mentioned above.

**UPDATE**

As for your OndataBinding Event above , if the last row is not updating, its pretty clear . May be `recordcount` is not equal 1 at the last row. Put a breakpoint there and see.Perhaps may be your query returns empty at the last row. That may be the case. Put a break point and see.

Comment: Thanks so much for this!! I'll try this and update you it worked! How about the last update that I have posted? the ondatabinding property in checkbox?

Comment: For sure, RecordCount at last row should be equal to 1 as per the subject i am using for testing, For example, the last row I'm testing is January 31, 2014, and that date has a confirmed data in the discount table, therefore RecordCount for that date shoule be equal to 1. You are right maybe it is returning wrong for an unidentified reason.

Comment: HI @NuruSalihu I have tried the backgroundWorker, but it is not working too, But the concept works when I input alort message on the workcomplete part, so I guess the error is still on checking the checkbox